# string.Split returning the entire string

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, file, split

Right now, I'm creating a reader for a file.

When I do the split with `Encoding.Unicode`, the result just returns the original string for some reason.

Here's the code:

```
string thefile = File.ReadAllText("file.bin", Encoding.Unicode); // also does the same if I do GetString() and ReadAllBytes

byte[] delim = { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00 };

string delims = Encoding.Unicode.GetStfring(delim);

string[] sep = new string[] { delims };

string[] res = thefile.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None);


int curr = 0;
foreach(string result in res)
{
    byte[] thing = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(res[curr]);
    File.WriteAllBytes("split" + curr, thing);
    curr++;
}
```

This doesn't happen if I use `Encoding.UTF8`, but some data is lost (`FF` -> `EF BF BD` in hex).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: `string delims = Encoding.Unicode.GetStfring(delim);` you have a typo should that be `GetString`

Comment: Are you actually trying to split text, or bytes? If you're trying to split text, why are you specifying the delimiter in bytes and then decoding it? Just put it in a string... It doesn't help that we don't know what's in your file. (If this isn't actually a text file though, *please* don't try using text-oriented methods. It's a disaster of an approach.)

Comment: `Encoding.Unicode` is UTF-16 little endian. Check for the endianness of your file and delimiter. But if you really want to manipulate binary data, you shouldn't be using strings in the first place.

Comment: @MethodMan: Yep, it's GetString. I accidentally put that there while pasting my code.

Comment: @JonSkeet: It's a binary file with text. I'm using string.Substring to get some things from the file.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: It's binary data, but I don't know how to do what I want to do without strings.

Comment: If it's binary data, don't read it with something designed to read text. Only convert the data that is genuinely encoded text into a string.

Comment: @RBLXDev then stop right there, and use a `FileStream` and a  `BinaryReader`. Using strings is a dead end.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary But how would I do something like string.Split()?

Comment: your Split() method works fine. its because your text-binary(!!) file does not contain `delims`. binary and text is completely opposite. binary is computer-readable while text is human-readable. you have to learn the structure of binary file. write the algorithm to read the binary file. or you can use libraries to do that for you.

Comment: The thing that bothers me is that it does. If I open a text editor, I can see it quite clearly, too.